# How to ensure duplicate partition key and rowkey combination throws a 412(pre-condition failed) exception in Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a table with pipeline name as the PartitionKey and tiemstamp as the RowKey. I have a number of nodes accessing this table. The node (does some processing) writes to the table a new record as long as the Partition key and row key combination is different. Any other node trying to add the same Partitionkey rowkey combination should get 412.
How to achieve this concurrency?

Comment: I presume you are using RowKey as a way of reducing duplicates (leaving first record only)? How are you gonna use it? Is it logs of some kind? (Im asking because I see low rating and assume you don't have much experience with cloud technology, so there might be better solution than using tables)

Answer (score 0):

> Any other node trying to add the same Partitionkey rowkey combination
> should get 412. How to achieve this concurrency?

It is not possible plus there's nothing special you would need to do.

When a user tries to insert an entity that has the same PartitionKey and RowKey value of an existing entity, table service will automatically throw `409 (Conflict)` error because combination of PartitionKey and RowKey uniquely identifies an entity in a table (kind of composite primary key).